# Mocking External Service with 'new' keyword in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am having trouble properly mocking a module that uses the `new` keyword to actually return what I want in my jest test.

My function looks like this:

```
 'myService.js'

export const checkMayFlyRecord = record => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const recId = crypto.createHash('md5').update(record.id + record.url).digest('hex')

    const mayflyClient = new mayfly({
      appName: 'cartrecoverynodeserv',
      lifetime: 24 * 3600, // store for 24 hours
      crypto: false
    })

    mayflyClient.read(recId, (err, response) => {
      console.log('yo dog')
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else if (response.status && response.status > 0) {
        mayflyClient.set(recId, JSON.stringify(record), (err, response) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else if (response.status && response.status > 0) {
            reject(err)
          }
          resolve('saved')
        })
      } else {
        resolve('found')
      }
    })
  })
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
/* global jest, describe, beforeAll, beforeEach, expect, test */

describe('myService', () => {
  let mayfly
  let dropoffsService
  let mayflyFunctions
  const records = [
    {'id': '2024876599037241006', 'url': 'jey.com'}
  ]

  beforeAll(() => {
    mayfly = jest.genMockFromModule('mayfly')
    jest.mock('mayfly')
    mayfly = require('mayfly')

    mayfly.read = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ status: 1 })
    mayfly.set = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ status: 1 })

    // mayflyFunctions = {
    //   set: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ status: 1 }),
    //   read: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ status: 1 })
    // }
    //
    // mayfly.mockImplementation(() => { mayflyFunctions })

    myService = require('./myService')
  })

  describe('checkMayFlyRecord', () => {
    test.only('mayfly calls the read function when connection is made', async () => {
      await myService.checkMayFlyRecord(records[0])
      expect(mayflyFunctions.read).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

With the test as is, I get the following error:
`Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.`

However, if I remove the `jest.mock('mayfly')`, then I reach my `yo dog` console log, and I get a connection error. This tells me that I must be doing something wrong with the way I am mocking the third party module `mayfly`. Normally, this is easy, but this is the first time I've had to mock a module where I have to use the `new` keyword.

You'll notice that commented out, I already tried using jest's `mockImplementation()` function, but couldn't get that working either.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mock methods need to invoke the callbacks passed to them. Try:

```
mayfly.read = jest.fn((recordId, callback) => {
    callback(undefined, {
    status: 200
    })
})
```